# Joomla 3.0 component cache issue

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I Newly Develop one Joomla Component for Matrimoney. I Installed this Component for one Joomla Site. When I Perform any Action in this Component Site Part (Ex. I Update Profile Information.)  that not Display Immediately. After  Cache Clear Performed Action will Display.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: When I Installed my Component Perform any Action. It should not Display. After Joomla Site Cache Clear. Its Display.

Answer (score 0):

Caching in Joomla is done for CSS and JS files not for php files. in case the component creates temporary caching of php files by creating new php files then it needs to be changed in the component configuration page. It can also be disable in Joomla configuration if you go to Global configuration and disable Joomla caching OR if you directly change `$caching =0;` in Joomla configuration.php file.

EDIT:
You can also use Cache Cleaner from nonumber which can update cache on saving https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/cachecleaner#free-vs-pro

Answer (score 0):

Install JotCache and explicitly specify in JotCache's settings not to cache your custom made component (disable the System - Cache plugin once you have it installed). That should solve your problem.